# The text won't cross out in Todo app in "React"

Tags: reactjs

I'm beginner and I'm working on Todo app in "React". I made a class with text-decoration: line-through and I want to cross out text when click on check_btn. But I don't know why  the text won't cross out.

```
const Task = ({ setTasks, tasks, id, title }) => {
  const deleteHandler = () => {
    setTasks(tasks.filter((el) => el.id !== id));
  };
  const completeHandler = () => {
    setTasks(
      tasks.filter((item) => {
        if (item.id === tasks.id) {
          return {
            ...item,
            completed: !item.completed,
          };
        }
        return item;
      })
    );
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <li>
        <div className={`task_name ${tasks.completed ? "completed " : ""}`}>
          {title}
        </div>
        <button className="delete_btn" onClick={deleteHandler}>
          <FaTimesCircle className="delete_item" />
        </button>
        <button className="edit_btn">
          <FaEdit className="edit_item" />
        </button>
        <button className="check_btn" onClick={completeHandler}>
          <FaCheckCircle className="check_item" />
        </button>
      </li>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: You are not checking if the task you are clicking is the actual task clicked probably use the event.target attribute to get the id and check it out

Answer (score 0):

You should use `map` instead of `filter` in `completeHandler`

- `filter` is to filter data conditionally
- `map` is to map a current object to another object

In your case, you change `completed` attribute in existing tasks means mapping data instead of filtering data.

Another problem is you use condition `if (item.id === tasks.id)` wrongly. It should be `if (item.id === id)` which is comparing to the current task id.

```
const Task = ({ setTasks, tasks, id, title }) => {
  //find the current task by task id
  const currentTask = tasks.find(task => task.id === id)

  //if cannot find any task by task id in the current tasks list
  //return nothing
  if(!currentTask) {
     return null
  }

  const deleteHandler = () => {
    setTasks(tasks.filter((el) => el.id !== id));
  };
  const completeHandler = () => {
    setTasks(
      //use `map` instead of `filter`
      tasks.map((item) => {
        //compare to the current task id instead of `tasks.id` (not existing)
        if (item.id === id) {
          return {
            ...item,
            completed: !item.completed,
          };
        }
        return item;
      })
    );
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <li>
        <div className={`task_name ${currentTask.completed ? "completed " : ""}`}>
          {title}
        </div>
        <button className="delete_btn" onClick={deleteHandler}>
          <FaTimesCircle className="delete_item" />
        </button>
        <button className="edit_btn">
          <FaEdit className="edit_item" />
        </button>
        <button className="check_btn" onClick={completeHandler}>
          <FaCheckCircle className="check_item" />
        </button>
      </li>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`tasks.completed` will always be `undefined`. `tasks` is the array of tasks, not an individual task inside that array.

What you want to do is check the value of `task.completed` for each `task` in the `tasks` array.